# Rotating Banner / Carousel With Other Web Parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

On my website's homepage, I'm looking to incorporate a rotating banner.

I have a selection of images (4), which currently change every 5 seconds.

However, what I would really like is to develop something similar to what Oracle has done - http://www.oracle.com/index.html

You can see their banner is made up of 3 parts:

1) The main image in the middle.
 2) A header - that displays an icon for each image.
 3) A footer which is by default hidden, but slides up upon a selection.

Any ideas of how I could even get started? I am using HTML and jQuery.

Thanks

**Update 29-05-13**

Apologies forgot to upload my current code:

**HTML:**

```js
    function rotateBanners(elem) {
       var active = $(elem+" img.active");
       var next = active.next();
       if (next.length == 0)
         next = $(elem+" img:first");
         active.removeClass("active").fadeOut(200);
       next.addClass("active").fadeIn(200);
    }

    function prepareRotator(elem) {
       $(elem+" img").fadeOut(0);
       $(elem+" img:first").fadeIn(0).addClass("active");
    }

    function startRotator(elem) {
       prepareRotator(elem);
       setInterval("rotateBanners('"+elem+"')", 2500);
    }
```

```css
    #rotator img { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="rotate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
            startRotator("#rotator");
            })
         </script>
      </head>
       <div id="rotator">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=1" />
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=2" />
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=3" />
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=4" />
       </div>
```

Comment: And what did you try?:)

Comment: It looks like a lot of animation so jQuery animate would be a good start. How are you doing the carousel now? Is that also jQuery and did you write that yourself?

Comment: Apologies, current code added above.